# How to store preferences without app being launched

Tags: android, persistence, sharedpreferences, android-assets

I have a version 1 of an app installed on the device. An app can be updated automatically to version 2.

I would like to save a constant string (defined at build time) in version 1 and read it in version 2. It might happen that app updates itself to version 2 before user runs version 1, so I cannot save my string programmatically.

Is there any way to declaratively define preference (or maybe have an asset file containing a value) which does not require a code to run and persist during update?

Comment: so the version 2 doesn't have the "constant string"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `raw` folder for that, you can store text files in this folder and then access them from your android applications .. but it is `only` for `reading`
see this tutorial

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/27/using-files-as-raw-resources-in-android/

Comment: I mentioned that user might not get chance to run the app, therefore I cannot use any code-based solution.

Comment: Google Play updates an app when a new version gets published.